# How to append values from jquery to table with multiples rows and columns

Tags: jquery, html

I got stuck when playing with JQuery and Table

I want to add value from textbox from a form to table after user click on a button

My form has 3 comboboxes and 3 of them are dyanmic ( values from comboboxes load from database)

when user enter into textbox, and click add button, values from comboboxes and textbox will be append into a div under the form

you can imagine my workflow like this

=============================================

```
     |  Express   | Standard | Premium
```

France   |***_*__*_*_***10****_*__*_*__**| **__*_*__*_*___**      |    20

England  |***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**|__*_*__*30* __   |

Portugal |***_*___***50****_*__*_*__**|__*_*__*_*__*_*_|    80

==============================================

When user click to choose country from combobox and choose the mode from combobx (i mean standard - express,etc...) and then enter number into textbox , it will appear under form (i use div and append table into div or append table into table), then it can get value and add it into column what I want

Example first click I Choose France - Express and 20, second click I choose Endland and Standard and 30, third click once again I choose France and Premium with value 15

Another problem -  I have one combobox for provider, it mean with Express has many providers like Express 1 - Express 2 - Express 3, so on.

When I choose France and Express again but different provider it will add to Express column and France Row this value

typing so hard to explain what I want

I will explain by diagram below like this step by step

First click :

==========================================

***_*__*_*_**    |   Express

France |   20

=================================================
Second click

---

```
   |    Express_____ |    Standard
```

France |***_*___**      20 **__*_*__*_*__**   |

England|   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**         |      30

---

Third clicks

=====================================================

```
   __|    Express |    Standard   |     Premium
```

France |  ***_*__*_*__**     20  ***_*__** |**__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**   |       15

England|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**|***_*__*_*___** 30***_*__*_***|

=====================================================

another problem

__*_*__ *|*__Express__*|*__     Standard  |     Premium

France |Express1 20 |**__*_*__*_*____**  |  Premium1 15, Premium3 20

England|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_***|*Standard2 30*|

=============================================================

my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#btAdd").click(function() {
                            var txtCost = $('#txtCost').val();
                            var ctryID = $('#CountryID').val();
                            var ctryName = $('#CountryID option:selected').text();
                            var modeID = $('#ModeID').val();
                            var modeName = $('#ModeID option:selected').text();
                            var ProviderID = $('#ProviderID').val();
                            var ProviderName = $('#ProviderID option:selected').text();
                            var HeaderTitle = $('#HeaderTitle').length;
                            var modenameID = $('#modeNameID'+modeName).text();
                            var CountryID = $('#Country'+ctryID).text();

                            if(HeaderTitle == 0){                                
                                $('#tblAppend').append(
                                    '<tr id="HeaderTitle"><td></td><td id="modeNameID'+modeName+'">'+modeName+'</td><tr>'
                                );
                            }else{
                               if(modeName != modenameID){
                                    $('#HeaderTitle').append(
                                        '<td id="modeNameID'+modeName+'">'+modeName+'</td>'
                                    );
                               }

                            }
                           if(CountryID != ctryName){
                                $('#tblAppend').append(
                                    '<tr id="nameCTR'+ctryID+'"><td id="Country'+ctryID+'">'+ctryName+'</td></tr>'
                               );


                           }

                            if(CountryID != ctryName && modeName != modenameID){
                                $('#nameCTR'+ctryID).append(
                                        '<td id="cost'+txtCost+'">'+txtCost+'</td>'
                                    );
                            }
                            if(CountryID != ctryName && modeName == modenameID){
                                $('#nameCTR'+ctryID).append(
                                        '<td id="cost'+txtCost+'">'+txtCost+'</td>'
                                    );
                            }
                            if(CountryID == ctryName && modeName != modenameID){
                                $('#nameCTR'+ctryID).append(
                                        '<td id="cost'+txtCost+'">'+txtCost+'</td>'
                                    );
                            }

                            if (CountryID == ctryName && modeName == modenameID){
                                $('#cost'+txtCost).append(
                                    '$'+txtCost
                                );
                            }

            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr> 
            <td><input  style="width:100px;" type="text" name="txtCost" id="txtCost" value=""/></td>
            <td>
                Country
                <select id="CountryID">
                  <option value="1">France</option>
                  <option value="2">USA</option>
                  <option value="3">Poland</option>
                  <option value="4">Vietnam</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Mode
                <select id="ModeID">
                  <option value="p1">Express</option>
                  <option value="p2">Standard</option>
                  <option value="P3">Premium</option>

                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Provider
                <select id="ProviderID">
                  <option value="A1">A1</option>
                  <option value="A2">A2</option>
                  <option value="A3">A3</option>

                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btAdd" name="btAdd" value="Add"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblAppend">
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Kency please create a fiddle using http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have ready this code please test and let me know if any thing missing

[jsfiddler demo running app available here](http://jsfiddle.net/JYeDa/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay" style="height:10px">               
            </div>
            <div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">Execute Sql</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">

<h2>Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btAdd").click(function () {
            var txtCost = $('#txtCost').val();
            var ctryID = $('#CountryID').val();
            var ctryName = $('#CountryID option:selected').text();
            var modeID = $('#ModeID').val();
            var modeName = $('#ModeID option:selected').text();
            var ProviderID = $('#ProviderID').val();
            var ProviderName = $('#ProviderID option:selected').text();
            var HeaderTitle = $('#HeaderTitle').length;
            var modenameID = $('#modeNameID' + modeName).text();
            var CountryID = $('#Country' + ctryID).text();

            if (HeaderTitle == 0) {
                $('#tblAppend').append(
                                    '<tr id="HeaderTitle"><td></td><td id="modeNameID' + modeName + '">' + modeName + '</td><tr>'
                                );
            } else {
                if (modeName != modenameID) {
                    $('#HeaderTitle').append(
                                        '<td id="modeNameID' + modeName + '">' + modeName + '</td>'
                                    );
                }

            }
            if (CountryID != ctryName) {
                $('#tblAppend').append(
                                    '<tr id="nameCTR' + ctryID + '"><td id="Country' + ctryID + '">' + ctryName + '</td></tr>'
                               );


            }

            if (CountryID != ctryName && modeName != modenameID) {
                $('#nameCTR' + ctryID).append(
                                        '<td id="mode' + ctryID + modeID + '"><div id="cost' + ctryID + ProviderID + modeID + '">' + ProviderName + ":" + txtCost + '</div></td>'
                                    );
            }
            if (CountryID != ctryName && modeName == modenameID) {
                $('#nameCTR' + ctryID).append(
                                        '<td id="mode' + ctryID + modeID + '"><div id="cost' + ctryID + ProviderID + modeID + '">' + ProviderName + ":" + txtCost + '</div></td>'
                                    );
            }
            if (CountryID == ctryName && modeName != modenameID) {
                $('#nameCTR' + ctryID).append(
                                        '<td id="mode' + ctryID + modeID + '"><div id="cost' + ctryID + ProviderID + modeID + '">' + ProviderName + ":" + txtCost + '</div></td>'
                                    );
            }

            if (CountryID == ctryName && modeName == modenameID) {
                //tr level chek if a mode is avila or not
                {
                    var contain = false;
                    $('#nameCTR' + ctryID).find('td').each(function (id, val) {                        
                        if ($(this).attr('id') == ("mode" + ctryID + modeID)) {
                            contain = true;
                        }
                    });
                    if (contain == false) {
                        //add cell to country
                        $('#nameCTR' + ctryID).append(
                                        '<td id="mode' + ctryID + modeID + '"><div id="cost' + ctryID + ProviderID + modeID + '">' + ProviderName + ":" + txtCost + '</div></td>'
                                    );
                    }

                }
                //td lelvel entry of value depend on provider
                {
                    if ($('#mode' + ctryID + modeID).find('div').text().indexOf(ProviderName) != -1) {
                        $('#cost' + ctryID + ProviderID + modeID).append(
                                    '$' + txtCost
                                );
                    } else {
                        $('#mode' + ctryID + modeID).append(
                                        '<div id="cost' + ctryID + ProviderID + modeID + '">' + ProviderName + ":" + txtCost + '</div>'
                                    );
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr> 
            <td><input  style="width:100px;" type="text" name="txtCost" id="txtCost" value=""/></td>
            <td>
                Country
                <select id="CountryID">
                  <option value="1">France</option>
                  <option value="2">USA</option>
                  <option value="3">Poland</option>
                  <option value="4">Vietnam</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Mode
                <select id="ModeID">
                  <option value="p1">Express</option>
                  <option value="p2">Standard</option>
                  <option value="P3">Premium</option>

                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Provider
                <select id="ProviderID">
                  <option value="A1">A1</option>
                  <option value="A2">A2</option>
                  <option value="A3">A3</option>

                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btAdd" name="btAdd" value="Add"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblAppend">
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </table>


        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```